# https://fcmregistrations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/registrations gives 401

Tags: firebase, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

Operating System
windows 11

Browser Version
chrome/116

Firebase SDK Version
10.3.1

Firebase SDK Product:
Messaging

Describe your project's tooling
its just a normal expo project where I want push notification

Describe the problem
when I call getToken I got 401 in [https://fcmregistrations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/registrations](https://fcmregistrations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%7Bproject_id%7D/registrations)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUy3L.png)

Steps and code to reproduce issue
simple calling getToken API

I am trying to call simple getToken API
and I am expecting a token in return